# common login screen from each controller action on session timeout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, controller, popup

We are implementing multi page MVC 4 web site. Here we require user to be authenticated all the time.

I am able to place login screen on Layout page and launch it on ajax click action in header.

**But our requirement is that, on every controller action, if session is invalid, we need to show login screen as popup else action should do its designated task.**

Please suggest how can i launch it from the controller. Currently we are using separate page for Login where we redirect when we found invalid session on any controller action.

Thanks and Regards,
Vikas Nale

Comment: Do you need to show the login screen after the page is rendered instead redirect by controller or when some action occurs? Ex: if the user stays in a page for a long time that the session expires and when he clicks in something you show the screen page via ajax?

Comment: Hi @japonex, you are correct, we need to show login screen if his session expires. Some of our screens are like user will be on the page doing changes over 2-3 days and want him to be on same state. Only while posting his changes, we will show login screen.  For first time, we will be redirecting him to blank screen with login box. But if we redirect on session expire, we wont be able to persist his changes and will be lost.   Thanks